# Unable to start a Intent activity inside onClick

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, start-activity

The startactivity() inside the new method is not getting called..i tried inside onclick() method..till i.putextra() method it is executing perfectly

```
public class First_Fragment extends Fragment{

View myView;
EditText figText;
Button figButton;
String TAG ="com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout,container,false);
    figText= (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.figText);
    figButton= (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.figButton);
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 1");
    figButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newMethod();
        }
    });

    return myView;
}


 public void newMethod()
  {
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 2");
    String id=figText.getText().toString();
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 3");
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), webView.class);
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 4");
    i.putExtra("sivMessage",id);
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 5");
     startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

the webview class code is as follows..

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class webView extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView figWeb;
String TAG ="com.myapplication.siva.sasfig";
long num;
String abc;
TextView regNo;

public webView() {
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    regNo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.regNo);
    figWeb = ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.figWeb));

    WebSettings webSettings = figWeb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Bundle man = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(man == null){
        return;
    }
    String sivMessage = man.getString("sivMessage");
    num=Long.parseLong(sivMessage);
    regNo.setText(sivMessage);
    figWeb.loadUrl("http://192.6.18/memberaccess1.asp?id="+num);
}
public void onPlus(View view)
{
    num+=1;
    abc=""+num;
    regNo.setText(abc);
    figWeb.loadUrl("http://192.6.18/memberaccess1.asp?id="+num);
}
public void onMinus(View view)
{
    num-=1;
    abc=""+num;
    regNo.setText(abc);
    figWeb.loadUrl("http://192.6.18/memberaccess1.asp?id="+num);
}
}
```

Logcat for the code is given below:this isedited log created by me...

```
 09-26 16:51:43.984  17879-17879/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer I/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer﹕ Going inside 1
 09-26 16:51:43.984  17879-17879/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer I/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer﹕ Going inside 2
 09-26 16:51:43.984  17879-17879/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer I/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer﹕ Going inside 3
 09-26 16:51:43.991  17879-17879/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer I/com.myapplication.siva.navigation_drawer﹕ Going inside 4
```

Comment: What is logcat saying?

Comment: Going inside 2 Going inside 3  Going inside 4   Going inside 5         after that the app gets closed

Comment: as you said app gets closed...possiblity of error so post logcat report along with second Activity

Comment: As mentioned by others *POST YOUR LOGCAT*. Also I suspect the problem is in your `webview` code and not in the code you've posted - post the code for `webview` as well as the logcat stacktrace. One last thing - starting an `Activity` from a `Fragment` isn't really good coding practice - the `Activity` holding the `Fragment` should be responsible for starting any new `Activities`.

Comment: have you try with _this_ or _First_Fragment.this_ ?

Comment: @Squonk i uploaded it...

Comment: @Siva : The logcat extract you posted shows nothing but the informal locg messages. If the app is being closed ther will be a stacktrace showing an unhandled exception - find that in logcat and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please do like below:

```
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getActivity().getBaseContext()`

```
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), webView.class);
     startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i can see no updation...can you be specific on what changes you've made...please

Answer (score 0):

You my want to try passing the `Context` to `newMethod`, i.e.:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        newMethod(getActivy());
    }
```

---

```
 public void newMethod(Context ctx)
  {
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 2");
    String id=figText.getText().toString();
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 3");
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, webView.class);
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 4");
    i.putExtra("sivMessage",id);
    Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 5");
     startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can try to place the dialog inside a [new Runnable()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921759/797495)

---

**Update Based on your comment**:

> This problem can be for used getActivity() of "android.app.Fragment"
>   or "android.support.v4.app.Fragment"
>
> if your are using "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" you need to review
>   if you aren't using getActivity from "android.app.Fragment" or vice
>   versa.

SRC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15908255/797495

Comment: You can try `getSupportActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public void newMethod()
      {
        Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 2");
        String id=figText.getText().toString();
        Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 3");

// The following line is edited.

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), webView.class);

        Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 4");
        i.putExtra("sivMessage",id);
        Log.i(TAG,"Going inside 5");
         startActivity(i);
       }
```

your mistake in this line

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), webView.class);
```